# Only I can initiate ubuntu 12.04 in my notebook, only if I place the memory USB with which I installed it

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb-creator

I installed ubuntu 12.04 from a memory USB, but now to be able to initiate my computer I must place the memory USB, if a black screen does not remain with a script blinking. I reinstalled it to see if it was solved but it followed the problem. How can I arrange it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like grub installed on the USB drive.
Try booting with the USB drive installed,
Safely remove the USB drive.
In terminal run:

```
update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

If

> sudo update-grub

didn't work, try

> sudo grub-install /dev/sda